# Android list-view expansion time animation

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-animation, recyclerview-layout

I have a list-view as illustrated in the following picture, which will expand as been shown in the 2nd picture to populate few more information about the selected item.

[image]

[image]

Now I need to add animation during this expansion transition(while expanding & closing). Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

My idea is to animate like a 'folded paper's opening' while expansion and then closing down back while exit (as shown below)

[image]

Comment: instead of listView Use RecyclerView in this case and then assigning proper animation to your recycler. it's much more easier.

Comment: Yes I can change to recycler view in that case but u got any hint how can I archive this?

Comment: here are some good ItemAnimation may help you https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView/

Comment: @AbuQauod this question is about expanding and collapsing animation not about creating list with standard expanding and collapsing